# PDO connection Error to the database

Tags: php, database, pdo

I am trying to run my project in my local machine but its bringing the following error:

> ERRNO: `2`
>  TEXT: `PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: The requested name is
>   valid, but no data of the requested type was found.  LOCATION:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\rsecrets\business\database_handler.php, line 25, at
>   December 4, 2012, 12:46 pm`

How I have defined the connection:

```
define('DB_PERSISTENCY', 'true');
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'xxyy');
define('PDO_DSN', 'mysql:host=' . DB_SERVER . ';dbname=' . DB_DATABASE);
```

Here is what is in line 25 in database_handler.php:

```
 self::$_mHandler =
          new PDO(PDO_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD,
                  array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => DB_PERSISTENCY));
```

What am i not getting?

Comment: Can you connect using command line: `mysql -u root -p -d xxyy -h localhost` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't have a valid IPv4 entry for `localhost` in your hosts file.

Run `notepad.exe` as an administrator and edit `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Make sure the following line appears (with no leading `#`)

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```